# Can groovy string interpolation be nested?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I'm trying to add parameter in Jenkins groovy shell script, then wonder if groovy string interpolation can be used nested way like this.

```
node{

    def A = 'C'
    def B = 'D'
    def CD = 'Value what I want'

    sh "echo ${${A}${B}}"
}
```

Then what I expected is like this;

```
'Value what I want'
```

as if I do;

```
sh "echo ${CD}"
```

But it gives some error that $ is not found among steps [...]

Is it not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
import groovy.text.GStringTemplateEngine

// processes a string in "GString" format against the bindings    
def postProcess(str, Map bindings) {
 new GStringTemplateEngine().createTemplate(str).make(bindings).toString()
}

node{

    def A = 'C'
    def B = 'D'

    def bindings = [
      CD: 'Value what I want'
    ]

    // so this builds the "template" echo ${CD}
    def template = "echo \${${"${A}${B}"}}"​
    // post-process to get: echo Value what I want
    def command = postProcess(template, bindings)

    sh command
}
```

Comment: I did not try it in jenkins. But if you run this script https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5098840017338368 it will print `echo ${CD}`. My guess is what the OP wanted. If not, then I did not understand the question.

Comment: What I was looking for is to print the value of CD - 'Value what I want'.

Comment: I updated my answer with a solution using GStringTemplateEngine. The only change is that you need to place your "place holders" in a map. The reason it is not simple to do it "nested" in one line is because Groovy actually processes the place holders in normal strings at compile time, so you can't simply do it when the placeholder NAME is only known at runtime (ie generated)

Comment: Thanks. I fixed some typo on your code and it works.

Answer (score 1):

In regard to the accepted answer, if you're putting values in a map anyway then you can just interpolate your [key]:

```
def A = 'C'
def B = 'D'
def bindings = [ CD: 'Value what I want' ]

bindings["${A}${B}"] == 'Value what I want'
```

Answer (score 0):

`${A}${B}` is not a correct groovy syntax.

The interpolation just insert the value of expression between `${}`.

Even if you change to the correct syntax and create `$` method, the result will not be what you want.

```
    def nested = "${${A}+${B}}"
    println nested


static $(Closure closure) { //define $ method
    closure.call()
}
```

`CD` will be printed.

Comment: Thanks. it looks like that so far, so I posted a question to confirm that if there is someone who might know.